# Knapsack p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m modified to unlimited elements

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

In the Knapsack problem, there is a list of elements, that each one of them contain weight and cost.
I would like to do a dynamic algorithm that will deal with the knapsack problem, but any element can be chosen more than once.

Comment: This is the [unbounded knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Unbounded_knapsack_problem). Wikipedia gives a clear explanation of the appropriate dynamic program.

Comment: Thanks that helped me alot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following solution from [GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-cost-to-fill-given-weight-in-a-bag/) demonstrates what you want to do with help of Algorithm, examples and implementation.

It is **Min-cost Knapsack** , you can add an item more than once.

**NOTE**: here object weights are the indices in array, starting at 1. i.e. `w[] = {1,2,3,4,5}`

`cost[]` is cost required when you add particular object.

If you add cost[1 ]=20 then w[1 ]=1 kg, cost[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR9w3.png)=10 then w[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR9w3.png)=2 kg and so on.

[image]

hope this helps.